# How I can describe name in multipart upload in openapi 3

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I will pass data in milliseconds in `name` filed in multipart upload:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="1564672251250";
```

According openapi 3 example:

```
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          profileImage:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

That matches:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileImage"; filename="image1.png"
{…file content…}
```

How can I describe `name`(literally form name) in schema and add description to it?

Comment: Do you mean that the value of `name` is dynamic?

Comment: yep! I saw that in openapi 2 we could explicitly describe form name. but don't see it in openapi 3